# Selector Menu Prime Faces em JSF

Tags: html-select

Estou tentando utilizar um selectorOneMenu do tipo PrimeFaces para meu projeto. Sua funcionalidade é a seguinte: Quero cadastrar um objeto do tipo Disciplina no DB, daí necessito do selector para incluir um objeto do tipo Professor na disciplina, para não efetuar a inclusão dos dados do objeto tipo Professor. Não estou conseguindo recuperar o nome de todos os professores para mostrar no selector quando for fazer a escolha. Alguma dica???

```
<h:outputLabel value="Selecionar um Professor" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="selectedProf" value="#{selectedProf.recuperarTodosProfessores}" label="Select" effect="fold" editable="true" panelStyle="width:250px">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecionar" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{curs.professor}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:commandLink value="Adicionar" update="display1" />
<p:outputPanel id="display1" style="width:250px;padding-left: 5px;margin-top: 10px">
    <p:dataList value="#{discip.professor}" var="curso">#{professor}</p:dataList>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Nesse caso tenho q resgatar a lista d objetos do tipo Professor e mostrar no selector, aparecendo apenas o nome do Professor para selecionar e add no atributo professor da classe Disciplina.

Comment: Adelino, coloque essa info na pergunta fazendo `edit` no post. Se precisar ajuda a formatar nós ajudamos. E apague depois o comentério aqui pois pertence à pergunta.

Comment: Juntei à pergunta veja se falta algo e apague os comentários para ficar mais limpo.

Answer (score 1):

Eu acho que vc está confundindo um pouco, o atributo `value` do `p:selectOneMenu` é onde fica guardado o professor selecionado e o `value` do `f:selectItems` é a sua lista de professores disponíveis.

Não esqueça de usar um `converter`.

Acredito que ficaria +ou- assim o seu código.

```
  <p:selectOneMenu id="selectedProf" value="#{curs.professor}" converter="SeuConverter" label="Select" effect="fold" editable="true" panelStyle="width:250px">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecionar" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{selectedProf.recuperarTodosProfessores}" var="professor" itemLabel="#{professor.nome}" itemValue="#{professor}" />
  </p:selectOneMenu>
```